# Calling a flow with trigger "when an HTTP request is received" yields an authentication error

Tags: authentication, power-automate

Calling a flow with trigger "when a HTTP request is received" yields an authentication error:

```
{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The authentication credentials are not valid."}}
```

I am the owner of the flow.

[image: My flow]

All sources I have read state that authentication for that type of flow trigger is anonymous, i.e. everybody can call it. Why can't I, and how can I fix that? The action I am using has no authentication settings in itself.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a result of how [Data Loss Prevention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/wp-data-loss-prevention) is set up in your tenant.

Indeed, the HTTP trigger can be called by anyone outside your organization. For this reason this trigger is usually in the 'Non-Business' tier. However, your flow definition also contains an action of the SharePoint Online connector ('Business' tier). DLP prevents mixing actions from the two tiers.
You should consult with someone having access to Power Platform admin center to check your DLP policy and verify the above.

Not sure if sending access tokens with the HTTP request could satisfy DLP.

Comment: Oooh yeah, my life just got a whole lot more complicated ... :D Thanks for the pointer.